# How to pase a JSON array in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, cocoa

I have a login form where the user can login only with the valid `memberID` and `password`. If the user enter correct enamel and password i get a result string contains the user information that the user created in the signup process, if it the password is wrong it shows the `status 400` as the result string, the result string is the json array which contains one f the above values, one thing is the if the success login occur it gives the `staus 200` along with the user information, my need is to retrieve the status message from the array and i need to validate it within the app, if the login success(`status 200`) it needs to be redirected to the main page; if it is(`status 400`) it shows a unsuccessful login message.
my code:
EDit

```
-(IBAction)_clicksbtnsignIN:(id) sender
{
    [_txtmemberId resignFirstResponder];
    [_txtpassword resignFirstResponder];

    NSString *connectionstring =  [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];

    if ([connectionstring length]==0) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"you are not connected to the internet" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];        
    }       
    else
    {
        //NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        NSString *emailString = _txtmemberId.text; // storing the entered email in a string.            
        // Regular expression to checl the email format.

        NSString *emailReg = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";

        NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailReg];
        //[pool drain];

        if (_txtmemberId.text.length == 0  || _txtpassword.text.length == 0) {
            UIAlertView *alertblnk = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"ALERT" message:@"Fill the required text fields" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [alertblnk show];

            [alertblnk release];
        }
        if (([emailTest evaluateWithObject:emailString] != YES) || [emailString isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            UIAlertView *loginalert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@" Alert" message:@"Invalid Email ID" delegate:self
                                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [loginalert show];

            [loginalert release];
        } 
        else {

            [_spinner startAnimating];

            NSString *uname = _txtmemberId.text;

            NSString *pwd   = _txtpassword.text;

            NSString *urlVal = @"http://dev.eltouchapps.net/api/?app=1&type=m1&action=t2&var1=";

            NSString *urlVal1 = [urlVal stringByAppendingString:uname];

            NSString *urlVal2 = [urlVal1 stringByAppendingString:@"&var2="];

            NSString *urlVal3 = [urlVal2 stringByAppendingString:pwd];              

            NSString * encodedString = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,(CFStringRef)urlVal3,NULL,               (CFStringRef)@"\n" "",kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedString];

            NSString *resultString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

            UIAlertView *loginalert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@" Message" message:resultString delegate:self
                                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [loginalert show];                
           [loginalert release];

            lblresult.text = resultString;
            NSString *responseString = [resultString responseString]; 
            NSLog(@"Got Profile: %@", responseString); 

            NSMutableDictionary *responseJSON = [responseString JSONValue]; 
            NSString *firstName;
            if ([[responseJSON valueForKey:@"Status"] isEqualToString:@"200"]) // if success
            {

                ParallelReadViewController *detailViewController = [[ParallelReadViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ParallelReadViewController" bundle:nil];

                //detailViewController.firstString = firstString;
                // ...
                // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

                [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

                [detailViewController release];
                // do something
                firstName = [responseJSON valueForKey:@"FirstName"];
            }
            }   
}
}
```

Result string is why i get from the server. I know there is parsing of JSONB array we want , but i didn't know how to done this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Maulik {"Status":"400"}if it is invalid username or password

Comment: @Maulik{"status":"200"with firstnme,lastnme,id,time.....} in ithe successful login

Comment: and what have you tried to parse it ???

Comment: NSString *responseString = [resultString responseString];
            NSLog(@"Got Profile: %@", responseString);
            
            NSMutableDictionary *responseJSON = [responseString JSONValue];   
            
           // NSString *firstString;
            NSString *firstName = [responseJSON objectForKey:@"400"];
                       if (400) {
nothing happens,i have import#JSON also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on assumption of your response , try below code

```
    NSString *resultString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];        
    NSMutableDictionary *responseJSON = (NSMutableDictionary *)[responseString JSONValue]; 
    NSString *firstName;
    if ([[responseJSON valueForKey:@"Status"] isEqualToString:@"200"]) // if success
    {
        // do something
        firstName = [responseJSON valueForKey:@"FirstName"];
    }
```

Hope it gives you an idea.

Comment: page ???? i am not getting what you actually want to do with success of login !!! I think you want to switch to the next view. right ?

Comment: NSString *responseString = [resultString responseString]; Error:programe recives sgrbt

Comment: ye yea,if the login success,it want t go t nether page

Comment: please see my edit in my question ,iput your code,is there any mistake?

Comment: what are you trying to do with NSString *responseString = [resultString responseString]; ???

Comment: i put the up[dated code3 but response string undeclared .got the error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5837/discussion-between-maulik-and-icoder)

Comment: just insert the result string to responsestring

Comment: Have a look on this link : http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/02/24/how-to-use-touch-json-and-sbjson/

Answer (score 0):

Check out this JSON framework: https://github.com/stig/json-framework/